# Number of k-element subsets of set $[n] = \{ 1, ..., n \}$ such that no pair of numbers $\{ a, b \}$ such that: $0 \leq |a-b| \leq 2$ belong to them.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I found that the number of $k$-element subsets of set $[n] = \{ 1, ..., n \}$ such that no pair of numbers $\{ a, b \}$ such that: $0 \leq |a-b| \leq 2$ belong to any of them is equal to ${n-2k+2}\choose{k}$. I would like to know why / prove it.

---

My solution:

We can think of those subsets as of binary sequences of length $n$ with $k$ ones and $n-k$ zeros.

To construct them in such way that there are at least $2$ zeros between each pair of ones we can take $n-2k$ zeros and put them in a row. There will be $n-2k-1$ places between them. We add one place before the sequence. Then we take $k$ pairs of $10$ and put them in one of those places. That way I get:

$${n-2k}\choose{k}$$

That way we satisfy the condition of not creating pairs of ones that are too close to each other. But we don't create sequences with one at the last place and we get not enough places to choose from.

I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Are you sure about $|a-b|\ge a$? This means that $a$ is either 1 or 2.

Comment: I am confused by your posting, specifically the title.  As I interpret the constraint, if $~1~$ is in the k-element  subset, then neither $~2~$ nor $~3~$ can also be in the k-element subset.  Further, if $~2~$ is in the k-element subset, then $~4~$ can not also be in the k-element subset.  These are the only constraints that I can infer from the title.

Comment: Assuming that the interpretation in the answer of Ricky is correct, then, going forward with your future MathSE postings, please make more of an effort to proofread your postings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the condition $a \leq |a-b| \leq 2$ is incorrect, the correct condition is just $|a-b| \leq 2$.

To ensure that the $1$'s are at least separated by two $0$'s, we can represent all the $1$'s except the first with a segment "$001$". Therefore, we have one initial $1$, $(k-1)$ "$001$" segments, and
$$n-1-3(k-1)=n-3k+2$$
$0$'s. The total number of elements we can choose from is
$$1+(k-1)+(n-3k+2)=n-2k+2$$
Therefore, the answer is $$\binom{n-2k+2}{n-3k+2}=\binom{n-2k+2}{k}$$

Answer (score 1):

Accepting the interpretation in the first paragraph of the answer of Ricky, the problem can be solved via Stars and Bars.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Line up the elements of the set $~\{1,2,\cdots,n\}~$ in a row, left to right, in ascending order.  Then remove the $~k~$ elements that will be used to form the k-element subset.

The remaining $~(n-k)~$ elements have now (potentially) been partitioned into $~(k+1)~$ islands.  For $~i \in \{1,2,\cdots, k+1\},~$ let $~x_i~$ denote the non-negative integer that represents the size of island $~i.$

Note that there is a bijection between each distinct k-element subset, and each ordered $~(k+1)$-tuple $~(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{k+1}),~$ where the ordered $~(k+1)$-tuple is formed based on the specification in the previous paragraph.

Further, the constraint that $~|a-b| > 2,~$ for each pair of elements $~a,b~$ in the k-element subset will be satisfied, if and only if, each of $~x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_k~$ is $~\geq 2.~$

Note that (for example) $~x_1 = 0,~$ merely signifies that $~1~$ is an element of the k-element subset.  Consideration of $~x_{k+1} = 0~$ is similar.

Thus, the number of satisfying k-element subsets is equal to the number of solutions to :

- $~x_1 + \cdots x_{k+1} = (n-k) ~: ~k,n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~(2k-2) + k \leq n.$
- $~x_1, \cdots, x_{k+1} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
- $~x_2, \cdots, x_k \geq 2.$

---

Application of Stars and Bars is straightforward here.

For $~i \in \{2,3,\cdots,k\},~$ let $~y_i = x_i - 2.~$

Then, you want the number of solutions to

- $~x_1 + y_2 + y_3 + \cdots + y_k + x_{k+1} = (n - k) - (2k-2) = n+2-3k.$
- $x_1, x_{k+1}, y_2, y_3, \cdots, y_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions is

$$\binom{[n+2-3k] + k}{k} = \binom{n+2-2k}{k}.$$